# MYSQL PHP getting average of a single field

Tags: php, mysql, average

I've made a form that allows users to submit their name, a comment and a score from 1-6, which  then is saved in a table in their respective fields; name, comment and score. I wan't to display the average score.

This is what I've found out so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(fieldName) FROM tableName");
```

How do I echo this out?

Answer (score 3):

Give your result an alias, It makes accessing it easier.

Use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) to get your results

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(fieldName) AS avg FROM tableName");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['avg'];
```

FYI, `mysql_*` is obsolete. Try PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: This worked, thanks!

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT AVG(fieldName) AS avg FROM tableName");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo $row['avg'];
  

  }