# Debugging assistance request. PHP and MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT: I fixed it. Don't know why but the returned value was somehow incorrect. Had to query for just ratingScore, put it into an array, using a while loop add everything up, then divide by the number of loops and then divide the total ratingScore by the number of loops. I bet I'm doing something wrong in the query. I don't like that much code being on my page though.**

I've got this query below that should return a rounded average of ratingScore (int) from the table 'rating'. For some reason, if I echo the query anywhere in the body of the page it breaks everything below the page. I know for a fact that the query TECHNICALLY should be working as I've printed the adventureID on this specific page and it returns 2 (i'm using similar code further down the page) and if I query this in phpMyAdmin I receive the result '5' as every rating in that table is 5. I've not been able to get this query working since last night. `$con` returns the correct connection information and I use it everywhere else in the page so that isn't the issue either.

```
$ratingQuery = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ROUND(AVG(ratingScore)) FROM rating WHERE adventureID LIKE '".$adv['adventureID']."'");
```

The ratingScore table:

ratingID
userID
adventureID
ratingScore

1
111
2
5

11
111
2
5

21
111
2
5

22
111
2
5

31
111
2
5

41
111
11
1

51
111
41
3

61
141
401
5

71
141
2
5

Comment: It might be better if you can include a little more context around this code - for example, what is `$adv`? When you say "if I echo the query", can you show the code where you're doing that? Do you mean that you're echoing the query specifically, or the results of the query? Have you tried taking some of the complexity out of your query to see if that works? What happens if you do a very simple `SELECT ratingScore FROM rating WHERE adventureID = 2`?

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain it in a bit more detail. When I say I try to echo the query I do indeed mean that I try to echo the result `echo $ratingQuery`. $adv is an array for my 'adventure' table and I use the same array value to display comments further down the page. I'll try to test the query with the value '2' just now.

Comment: The 'basic' query still breaks the code. I'll try to only return the average without rounding it.

Comment: So I found that I can't print the returned result. If I query for just the ratingScore and then fetch the return value as an array I can print out all of the ratings. ROUND() and AVG() doesn't work for some strange reason.

Comment: OK! We got there :) You now know what the actual problem is (querying the database for an average), so you could try searching that to find the proper solution. I've done it for you though, and the answer [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19941050/325900). I'd highly recommend this technique for future debugging; get the code to the simplest you can make it that still exhibits the problem and you might find that it's obvious :)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for the help :)